# What parameters does a function takes

Tags: node.js, arangojs

I am trying to create an edgeCollection via node command line. I think the `db.edgeCollection` does this for me. What I don't know is what **extra** parameters does the function take in order to create a new edge collection.

I am currently using arangojs version 2.15.9

```
var database = require("arangojs").Database;
var db = new database(http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8529)

db.edgeCollection(##What should I write here to create a new edge collection?##)
```

It would be nice if there is a global way of knowing the parameters required by any function.

I am using vim as my code editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show function parameters in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741542/show-function-parameters-in-vim)

Answer (score 0):

I think if I understand your question correctly you need to go with arangojs documentation.
Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/arangojs

If you are using vim editor you lose so many suggestion opportunities provided by IDEs like eclipse,Idea or even notepad++

Comment: I already checked the documentation and it does not talk about creating edge collections. I can use an already existing edge collection but can not create one.

Answer (score 0):

To create an edgeCollection all I needed to do was this

```
var collection = db.edgeCollection("new-edge");
collection.create();
```

This solves the first part. And I am really sorry for not looking for the answer more because there is already a thread that answers the 2nd part of the question.
[show function parameters in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741542/show-function-parameters-in-vim)